# How do I gain access to my C: drive after completely locking it down?

Tags: windows, powershell, administrator, uac

I know the title might seem completely ridiculous but please read this before being biased.

Okay, so I got myself into a real squeeze. I installed Windows 10 technical preview for Enterprise on a test machine. After the installation was complete and all my updates and software was installed, I played around with the C: drive's permissions but didn't save any changes well I'm not completely sure because it happened quite fast. But now I'm completely locked out of my C: drive.

What do I mean?

I mean, I can't gain access to any files on my C: drive, I can't view my SQL Databases or even create new ones. I get the Access Denied error whenever I try to access the C: drive. I can't even install new software. When I navigate to "Local Disk (C:) -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced" and try to make any changes regarding permission, Auditing, Effective Access or even try to change the owner I get the same error "Access is Denied" and the current text under owner displays "Unable to display current owner."

So what have I tried?

First I booted into safe mode with command prompt and tried the following steps in the link below regarding the default Administrator account. https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130310010714AA0SjfA

Then I tried granting myself permission from the "Recovery" menu at boot time using Command Prompt as explained in the link below. "Choose "recover or maintain your system"-> Troubleshoot->Advanced Options->Command Prompt" http://community.sony.com/t5/Windows-8/c-drive-not-accessible-after-windows-8-refresh/td-p/64865/page/2

The above all returned "Access is Denied"

I tried refreshing and resetting my PC but each menu returns the unable to complete "C: Drive is Locked" I even tried to Disable UAC from powershell.

I haven't tried booting from a CD/DVD yet since I don't have one at the moment.

I don't mind wiping my C: Drive and re-installing an OS but I've tried booting from a USB Flash Drive and that just return another error: "Boot Device Failed. Press OK To Continue".

Any suggestion would be of great help at the moment. And anyone whose ever had this issue and solved it please let me know.

If you need further information please let me know, but I'm sure this should be enough.

Comment: If possible try to add this HDD as a secondary HDD on another machine and try to change the permission of C drive

Comment: Time to reinstall the operating system, you have placed the permissions into a state that cannot be recovered from in the future don't change the permissions

Comment: Have you tried using icacls?

Comment: It's a laptop so I don't really want to open it and take out the HDD but if I have to I will. I've tried both "icacls" and "takeown" I guess I'll just have to get a CD/DVD and try to reinstall it again. I always create a new folder in my C drive with special permissions since that's where I store and test all solutions so I have to edit and view permissions but this has never happened to me before.

Comment: In Safe Mode, logged in as Administrator you should be able to take ownership of drive C:, then reset the permissions. You do not need any valid permissions to do this. Anyone that is a member of the built-in Administrators group can forcibly take ownership, and then an Owner can change permissions to whatever he wishes. How exactly did you go about using TAKEOWN?

Comment: I restarted my PC and went into the recovery mode by pressing F11. Once in "TroubleShoot -> Advanced Settings -> Command Prompt" and that's where I tried to take own of the C drive.